# How do I draw a fine line like TreeView

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi, pen

I would like to be able to draw a file line using native Windows API (`LineTo`) like the one that TreeView uses to connect nodes to each other. But using `RS_DOT` to create the brush (`::CreatePen(PS_DOT, 0, RGB(200, 200, 200))`), produces a different kind of line. Does anyone know how I can draw such a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating a true dotted pen](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/DOTTED_PEN.aspx)

```
LOGBRUSH LogBrush;
LogBrush.lbColor = c_colorGridLine;
LogBrush.lbStyle = PS_SOLID;
penDotted.CreatePen( PS_COSMETIC | PS_ALTERNATE , 1, &LogBrush, 0, NULL );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help the actual code I used was:

LOGBRUSH lb = {BS_SOLID, RGB(200, 200, 200), 0};

hPen = ::ExtCreatePen(PS_COSMETIC | PS_ALTERNATE | PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE | PS_JOIN_ROUND, 1, &lb, 0, NULL);

Comment: Yeah, the code posted here assumes MFC. It's quite easily translatable to plain Win32, but that's not what it is. Explains why it wasn't accepted. @Sam, you should post your own answer as an answer, then accept it. You might want to upvote this one, though, as it got you on your way to the solution.